# Show/Hide Image Caption on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Building a portfolio page with images and trying to use jquery to make the caption show and slide up on hover but then, when i tried, it didn't work with my code. The code is shown below plus a snippet that can also be run.

Here's a Snippet

```js
$('.port-img').hover(function() {
  if ($(".caption").is('hidden')) {
    $(this).show('slideUp', 'slow');
    $(this).hide('slideDown', 'slow');
  };
});
```

```css
.caption {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all .5s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section-1-port filter logo">
  <div class="port-img image">
    <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="Bams Nigeria Enterprise" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="caption img-caption">
    <h3>Logo Design, Photoshop</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with alternative way, using CSS only :

```css
.caption-style-2{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 
}

.caption-style-2 li{
 float: left;
 padding: 0px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.caption-style-2 li:hover .caption{
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translateY(-100px);
 -webkit-transform:translateY(-100px);
 -moz-transform:translateY(-100px);
 -ms-transform:translateY(-100px);
 -o-transform:translateY(-100px);

}


.caption-style-2 img{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 float: left;
 z-index: 4;
}


.caption-style-2 .caption{
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 top:300px;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.15s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:all 0.15s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition:all 0.15s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition:all 0.15s ease-in-out;
 transition:all 0.15s ease-in-out;

}
.caption-style-2 .blur{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 height: 300px;
 width: 400px;
 z-index: 5;
 position: absolute;
}

.caption-style-2 .caption-text h1{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.caption-style-2 .caption-text{
 z-index: 10;
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 text-align: center;
 top:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="caption-style-2">
 <li>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="">
  <div class="caption">
   <div class="blur"></div>
   <div class="caption-text">
    <h1>Amazing Caption</h1>
    <p>Whatever It Is - Always Awesome</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'll go with the option of using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.port-img').hover(function(){
 $(".caption").show('slideUp');
 $(".caption").hide('slideDown');
});
```

```css
.caption {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all .5s;
  display: none;
}



.image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section-1-port filter logo">
  <div class="port-img image">
   <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="Bams Nigeria Enterprise" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="caption img-caption">
   <h3>Logo Design, Photoshop</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
```

`$(this)` means `$('.port-img')`  not `('.caption')`

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at snippet.

```js
$('.port-img').hover(function(){
  var $caption = $(".caption");
  if ($caption.is(':hidden')){
    $caption.slideDown('slow');
  } else {
    $caption.slideUp('slow');
  }
});
```

```css
.caption {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all .5s;
  display: none; /* default hide */
}



.image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section-1-port filter logo">
  <div class="port-img image">
   <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="Bams Nigeria Enterprise" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="caption img-caption">
   <h3>Logo Design, Photoshop</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
```